# Cannot get the URL parameter correct for Google-Apps-Script REST API into firestsore

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

From here
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/get
I keep getting the error:
The requested URL /v1/projects/transaction1-111/databases/data/test1 was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

My database id: transaction1-111
Database: data
collection: test1

However it does not go through.
Yes I authorized
Yes I include the correct scopes

```
function example5() {


var options = {
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
  method:'GET',
  payload: JSON.stringify({fields: { title: { stringValue: 'newTitle' } } }),
  contentType: "application/json",
  muteHttpExceptions:true
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/transaction1-111/databases/data/test1', options);

Logger.log(response.getContentText());


}
```

Also how do I know what version I am using ie rest/v1 or rest/v2 or rest/beta...

Comment: About `From here https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/get I keep getting the error` in your question, in this case, "Method: projects.databases.get" is GET method. But it seems that your script doesn't use this method. How about this?

Comment: That's correct instead of GET I meant POST. But still it cannot find my firestore url. Also, can you give an example? Maybe I'm not understanding how to use it. Ty

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `That's correct instead of GET I meant POST.`, you have used the GET method of "Method: projects.databases.get" as the POST method. Is my understanding correct? I still cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Just help me make the URL format work. Have you used the URL before? Did you get it to work to connect to firestore?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question from your question and goal. But when I could correctly understand it, I would like to try to think of the solution.

Comment: I am trying to connect to Firestore from Apps Script so I can put data into my Firestore database.